# Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 2097152 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 12288 bytes)

Tags: magento2, memory, docker

I'm getting the next error after docker-compose up.

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 2097152 bytes exhausted (tried to
>   allocate 12288 bytes) in
>   /var/www/html/vendor/zendframework/zend-modulemanager/src/ModuleManager.php

Magento ver. 2.1.7
I'm using `mageinferno/magento2-php:7.0-fpm-1`

Here is docker-compose code:

```
version: '3'
services:

phpfpm:
    build: ./.docker/phpfpm
    links:
        - database
    volumes:
        - ./:/var/www/html
    environment:
        - XDEBUG_CONFIG=remote_host=10.200.10.1
        - PHP_IDE_CONFIF=serverName=terp
```

> nginx:
>       build: ./.docker/nginx
>       links:
>           - phpfpm
>       volumes:
>           - .:/var/www/html
>       ports:
>           - "8083:80"
>
> database:
>       image: mysql:5.7
>       environment:
>           - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=qwerqwer
>           - MYSQL_DATABASE=terp
>           - MYSQL_USER=terp
>           - MYSQL_PASSWORD=qwerqwer
>       ports:
>           - "3311:3306"
>       volumes:
>           - ./mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql

What could be the reason of that?

Comment: Looks like your memory limit (either PHP or docker) is set to 2mb.

Comment: But I set limit to 2G

Comment: I think php disagrees. Put 'phpinfo()' into index.php and double check

Comment: I have about the same pb: Magento2 is ok, then i empty cache, and bam: memory limit, and then i have to restart my containers... without even being sure it will work -_-

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by adding the actual value directly inside the php.ini file and mounting my custom version of it in the container. Apparently the variable PHP_MEMORY_LIMIT is not there when running the cron.

You can see the default `php.ini` file here https://github.com/mageinferno/docker-magento2-php/blob/master/conf/php.ini